# Error: -2147188160 Slides.Item: Integer out of range.2 is not in in index's valid range of 1 to 1 VBA power point error

Tags: vba, runtime-error, powerpoint

I'm trying to extract few specific slide numbers from each ppt and trying to paste them into a single ppt using VBA.But Im facing this error.Im quite new to VBA ,so it would be of great help how to proceed further.

Tried with the suggestions given in the link [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/285472/run-time-error-2147188160-on-activewindow-or-activepresentation-call-i#:~:text=This%20behavior%20is%20caused%20by,code%20will%20cause%20this%20error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/285472/run-time-error-2147188160-on-activewindow-or-activepresentation-call-i#:%7E:text=This%20behavior%20is%20caused%20by,code%20will%20cause%20this%20error).

But it is not working

Thanks in Advance

My code is as follows:

```
Sub sample()
   Dim objPresentation As Presentation
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim sListFileName As String
    Dim sListFilePath As String
    Dim iListFileNum As Integer
    Dim sBuf As String
    

    ' EDIT THESE AS NEEDED
    ' name of file containing files to be inserted
    sListFileName = "LIST2.TXT"

    ' backslash terminated path to folder containing list file:
    sListFilePath = "path"

    ' Do we have a file open already?
    If Not Presentations.Count > 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' If LIST.TXT file doesn't exist, create it
    If Len(Dir$(sListFilePath & sListFileName)) = 0 Then
        iListFileNum = FreeFile()
        Open sListFilePath & sListFileName For Output As iListFileNum
        ' get file names
        sBuf = Dir$(sListFilePath & "*.PPT")
        While Not sBuf = ""
            Print #iListFileNum, sBuf
            sBuf = Dir$
        Wend
        Close #iListFileNum
    End If

    iListFileNum = FreeFile()
    Open sListFilePath & sListFileName For Input As iListFileNum
    ' Process the list
    While Not EOF(iListFileNum)
        ' Get a line from the list file
        Line Input #iListFileNum, sBuf

        ' Verify that the file named on the line exists
        If Dir$(sBuf) <> "" Then
            Dim SlideArray As Variant
            'Set variable to Active Presentation
            
            Set OldPPT = ActivePresentation
            'Create a brand new PowerPoint presentation
            
            If PowerPoint.Application.Version >= 9 Then
                    'window must be visible
                   PowerPoint.Application.Visible = msoTrue
            End If
            
            
            Set NewPPT = Presentations.Add

            InSlides = InputBox("List the slide numbers separated by commas:", "Slides", 2)

            SlideArray = Split(InSlides, ",")
           
            For x = 0 To UBound(SlideArray)
               sld = CInt(SlideArray(x))

               'Set variable to a specific slide
               Set Old_sld = OldPPT.Slides(sld)

               'Copy Old Slide
               y = Old_sld.SlideIndex
               Old_sld.Copy

               'Paste Slide in new PowerPoint
                NewPPT.Slides.Paste
                Set New_sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

               'Bring over slides design
                New_sld.Design = Old_sld.Design

               'Bring over slides custom color formatting
                New_sld.ColorScheme = Old_sld.ColorScheme

               'Bring over whether or not slide follows Master Slide Layout (True/False)
                New_sld.FollowMasterBackground = Old_sld.FollowMasterBackground

           Next x
                          
        End If
        
    Wend

    Close #iListFileNum
    MsgBox "DONE!"

NormalExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Call MsgBox("Error:" & vbCrLf & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, _
                      vbOKOnly, "Error inserting files")
    Resume NormalExit

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set OldPPT = ActivePresentation`... does the active presentation have more than one slide?

Comment: No BigBen it has only 1 blank slide

Comment: It's curious that you're specifying `2` as the default in `InSlides = InputBox("List the slide numbers separated by commas:", "Slides", 2)`... but in any case, what did you enter into the `InputBox`? The error message is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yeah 2 is the default slide number.Im entering a list of slide numbers separatedby commas

Comment: Comment out the error handler code until you have working code.

Comment: I just tried removing the error handler it still shows the same error but the debugger is pointing to this line Set Old_sld = OldPPT.Slides(sld)

Comment: Presentations.Add will create a new presentation with no slides. It's easy to assume that it'll behave the same as creating a new presentation in the UI, which DOES always start with one slide. Try adding a slide to NewPPT before doing anything else. You can always delete it later.